# Feign return data

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign

I use feign to get a userIdList of Long.

> feign:

```
@GetMapping("getUsername/{userId}") 
ResultBean getUsername(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId);
```

ResultBean:

```
public class ResultBean<T>{
    private String statusCode;
    private T data;
}
```

method getGroupUserIds:

```
@GetMapping("getGroupUserIds/{groupId}")
@ResponseBody
public ResultBean getGroupUserIds(@PathVariable Long groupId){
    List<Long> userList = ssoService.getGroupUserIds(groupId);
    logger.info("getGroupUserIds返回{}:{}",groupId,userList.size());
    return new ResultBean(ResultBeanConstant.OK, userList);
}
```

method getByUserId:

```
public Channel getByUserId(Long userId) {
        return channels.get(userId);
    }
```

But when I use the value:

```
            List<Long> userIds = (List<Long>) resultBean.getData();
            log.info("userIds:{}",userIds.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < userIds.size(); i++) {
                Channel channel = getByUserId(userIds.get(i));
                if (channel!=null) {
                    channelList.add(channel);
                }
            }
```

it reports:**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**

I don't know where is wrong, logs are all ok, value have bean fetched and return. But why Long has be changed into Integer?

Comment: try `List<Integer> userIds = (List<Integer>) resultBean.getData();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use enhanced for loop. you are getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long` because you are using `int` in you for loop but your `userIds` are `Long` type hence they are not compatible.

```
List<Long> userIds = (List<Long>) resultBean.getData();
log.info("userIds:{}",userIds.size());
for (Long userId : userIds) {
     Channel channel = getByUserId(userId.intValue());
     if (channel!=null) {
         channelList.add(channel);
     }
}
```

Comment: What is parameter type in `getByUserId()` method ? int or `Long` ? Please add your  `getByUserId` method.

Comment: Your solution not solve the problem of the OP, all you changed is the for syntax, that's all

Comment: The problem is clear, the OP expect Integer but use Long this is the issue

Comment: @YCF_L if OP wants integer then he can use `intValue()` to convert Long to integer.

Comment: I use  `Long userId = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(userIds.get(i)));`  to convert the vlue to Long, and it works. But why I defined the type as Long, it turns out to be Integer?